# Can you use the water flow exiting a hydroelectric generator to generate more energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy, power, electrical-engineering, renewable-energy

In videos of hydroelectric generators I often see that the water that exits a turbine is still moving with significant velocity.

Example of a turbine that has exit water flow with significant velocity:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bhyi1DjGti8

Why don't we capture the kinetic energy of the water after this turbine with a second turbine? Why don't we continually chain turbines to convert as much energy as possible so that the water barely dribbles when it exits?

Follow up: If we can capture energy after each generator, I'd imagine we'd have some sort of converging sum with the first term being the efficiency of the first turbine times the theoretical amount of energy you can extract, then the second term would be its efficiency times the amount of remaining energy and so on.

Comment: This actually belongs on Engineering SE, not physics. But if you extracted all the energy so the water flow is zero, no new water would flow in. Even reducing outflow past a certain point hurts efficiency by impeding inflow (even on the input of the same turbine, let alone every turbine before it). That means there's a sweet spot. So-called Betz's Law. There are also practical considerations such as the mass of the materials used to make the turbines as you get to lower head pressures.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and common in practice, for a water-driven turbine to extract over 90% of the power flowing through it (see *Francis turbine* for example); in this case the water exiting the turbine basically falls freely out the bottom and sloshes away.

Not all turbine applications are ideally suited for the Francis design, and in these cases the water exiting the turbine works will carry with it significant amounts of velocity.

This does not mean that the residual kinetic energy of that exiting water can be economically harvested with a second turbine; instead, what is usually done is to scale up the first turbine to its largest possible proportions (which is almost always more efficient and cost-effective than concatenating two separate turbines).

It is however a good idea for the water leaving the turbine to carry some residual velocity with it if for no other reason than to simply get it out of the way so it doesn't pool up and flood the turbine works.